# GPGPU emulation

Tags: emulator, virtualization, gpu

What software would you recommend for GPGPU emulation to support compiling and running CUDA and OpenCL?

The aims would be:

- to learn and keep up to date with changes to CUDA and OpenCL
- estimate the effect of the various APIs on performance.
- to test that your code works on a variety of different platforms.

Other criteria to minimise search

- It should ideally target Linux
- It should be open source

There are at least two active emulation projects maintained as of October 2022:

- [gpgpu-sim](https://github.com/gpgpu-sim/gpgpu-sim_distribution/tree/dev)
- [oclgrind](https://github.com/jrprice/Oclgrind) - openCL device simulator

How good are these and how commonly they are used compared to using real GPUs (either your own or rented)? Are there any other choices worth looking at?

---

### Aside

The question of compiling and runnning GPU code for CUDA or OpenCL on a machine that does not natively support it has come up on stack overflow several times. It does not age well and typically gets closed as off-topic.
As its like a recommendation question I thought I would see how it fairs here.

I posted some of my notes as an answer to a previous stackoverflow question that was not closed https://stackoverflow.com/a/74266084/1569204

A more expert opinion would benefit the community.

Comment: I don't think its a very large search space but I've added Linux and open source as requirements.